# Google BigQuery Sandbox

Tags: google-bigquery

I am looking at Google BigQuery API and couldn't find any info regarding any sandbox or developer account, so if I just want to test it before I try, I still have to pay, correct? just wanna confirm.

Thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to try it out without paying, you're just limited to 10,000 requests a day after which you'd need to pay to continue using it.

Just go to your api console, make a new project, and activate BigQuery from the list. When you do you'll be asked to sign the agreement, which does have a payment terms section that states:

> 3.1. Free Quota. The Service is provided to Customer without charge up to the Fee Threshold.

You can take a look at the pricing page here: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/pricing

Comment: This is correct. If you don't enable billing, you're also limited to querying 100GB/month and are limited to queries of publicly-available datasets (you cannot load your own data).

Comment: @JordanTigani Ah yes, added a link to the pricing page with the 100GB/month fine print.

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery sandbox launched last friday (Feb 1st) which allows you to try BQ free without a CC, just need a gmail account. Check the docs out here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/sandbox

or from the BQ marketing page: 
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/